# Mysterious typecheck error in f# (missing when ?12345 :> ISomething)

Tags: f#

I have a fragment of F# that is not correctly typed. I am guessing that I need to constrain 'a1 and 'b1 to ISomething but I don't know how. There are two errors, both on the bottom line. The uses of f and g on the RHS are underlined, and the error message reads: A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when '?123456 :> ISomething' The only difference is that the message for g contains a mysterious number one higher than that for f. Many thanks.

```
type ISomething =
    abstract getint : int

type IOther<'a, 'b> =
    abstract map : ('a->'a1) -> ('b->'b1) -> IOther<'a1, 'b1>

type sometype<'a, 'b when 'a :> ISomething and 'b :> ISomething> (a:'a, b:'b) =

    member this.map (f:'a->'a1) (g:'b->'b1) : sometype<'a1, 'b1> = sometype (f a, g b)

    interface IOther<'a, 'b> with
        member x.map (f:'a->'a1) (g:'b->'b1) = x.map f g :> IOther<'a1,'b1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your map function specifically constructs a `sometype` instance.

In this case, since you're creating an `IOther<'a, 'b>` directly using your local map function, and the map function *requires* `'a1` and `'b1` to implement `ISomething` (because you create a new `sometype` instance), there's a missing constraint for the interface implementation.

You can work around it *in this case* by adding the constraint to `IOther<'a, 'b>`'s map function, ie:

```
type IOther<'a, 'b> =
    abstract map<'a, 'b, 'a1, 'b1 when 'a1 :> ISomething and 'b1 :> ISomething> : ('a->'a1) -> ('b->'b1) -> IOther<'a1, 'b1>
```

This would cause the `sometime.map` function to work within the constraints you have specified, though it restricts all `IOther<'a, 'b>` instances to only work with `ISomething`.

If that isn't adequate, the other option would be to change `sometype.map` to construct a type that doesn't have the constraints.